# My recursive greatest common denominator function isn't working properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a GCD (greatest common denominator) function using recursion.
I cannot understand why it isn't working properly.
For input 10 and 50 is returning 36.

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Rez=%d ", gcd(10,50));
    return 0;
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    static int n=0;
    int result=1;
    n++;
    if(a<=1 || b<=1)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        if(a%n==0 && b%n==0)
            result=n* gcd(a/n,b/n);
        else
            gcd(a,b);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `gcd(a,b);` -> `return gcd(a,b);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky tried that, the result is now 216 :)

Comment: With `static int n=0;` the function can only be used *once* in any given program run.

Comment: Stick to the standard Euclidean algorithm unless you can improve on it – this is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Side note, `gcd` is the greatest common *divisor*, not denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a static variable is a problem because you use it in the form `n * gcd(...)` and the value of n shouldn't be the same than that used by the recursion. So you should pass a parameter instead. You should also add a condition to stop when n becomes greater than the smaller term :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", gcd(10, 50, 1)); //==>10
    printf("%d\n", gcd(7, 35, 1));  //==>7
    printf("%d\n", gcd(8, 22, 1));  //==>2
    printf("%d\n", gcd(49, 5, 1));  //==>1
    printf("%d\n", gcd(0, 0, 1));   //==>1
    printf("%d\n", gcd(4, 2, 0));   //==>0
    return 0;
}

int gcd(int a, int b, int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) return 0;
    if (n > (a < b ? a : b) || a<=1 || b<=1) return 1;
    else if(a%n==0 && b%n==0) return n * gcd(a/n, b/n, n+1);
    else return gcd(a, b, n+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the static variable is the cause for the error. In

```
result=n* gcd(a/n,b/n);
```

`n` is evaluated *after* the recursion is called. So, as your recursion stops when you call `gcd( 5/5, 25/5 )` and `n` is incremented to 6 by that call you just have
6 * gcd( 10/1, 50/1 ) = 6 * 6 * gcd( 10/2, 50/2 ) = 6 * 6 * 6 = gcd( 5/5, 25/5 ) = 6 * 6 * 6 * 1 = 216